# Finding queue name of a resque job while its being processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

My Ruby project contains many queues and I want to know if I can find which queue the current processing jobs is coming from as I need to make some decision in my code based on the queue name.
There is a possible solution to add a queue name as a parameter to the job when we add it but I need to know if there is a built-in easy way to find it

Thanks

Comment: There's a queue attribute on the job --> https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/7623b8dfbdd0a07eb04b19fb25b16a8d6f087f9a/lib/resque/job.rb#L3

Comment: That's interesting. How will I get the Job object inside my code? any idea

Comment: without seeing your code impossible to say